# VBA: Taking Value from User Form and Inserting in Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take user input from a macro and copy that string for the length of the column (ideally as long as my first column has contents)

For example:
What country are you in?

User Input: **United States**

```
Column1    Column2

Steve      United States

Bill       United States

Blank      United States

Alice      United States
```

Comment: Sorry, no. My only experience is in JAVA. I'm trying to figure out some commonalities before I write anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring a lot of error-checking / ensuring answers were put in, here's the easiest way to do that:

```
  Sub Test()

  Dim Answer As String

  Answer = InputBox("What country are you in?")
  Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")).Offset(0, 1).Value = Answer

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go. This sub will only fill in the corresponding cell in **column B** if the cell in **column A** is **not blank**.

It iterates over each item in Column A, checks whether or not the cell is blank, and then places the 'Answer' string in Column B if the cell is not blank.

```
Sub country()

Dim Answer As String, i As Range

Answer = InputBox("What country are you in?")

For Each i In ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A300000").End(xlUp))

    If i <> vbNullString Then
        i.Offset(0, 1).Value = Answer
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```